# Limitations of the Telekinesis power

Tags: savage-worlds, deadlands-reloaded

One of my PCs has the Telekinesis Power, and I'm trying to get my head around its limitations. The Power is clear in indicating it's limits regarding size and weight, but I'm particularly interested in the phrasing of the beginning of the Power's description. It states that you can use Telekinesis to move a single object, and I wanted to check exactly what a 'single object' refers to in this context.

An example came up in the previous session I ran where the group was under attack from bandits on a steam wagon. The PC wanted to use Telekinesis to wrench the wagon's steering wheel up and off of the wagon altogether. At the time I ruled this was OK, as I figured that the steering wheel was an object in its own right, but now I'm not sure whether this was a correct call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no RAW defining this particular aspect, I would say it is ultimately a matter of DM interpretation.

This makes the most sense to me, for what it may be worth.

**An object which is *not* attached to a surface/object by any other object**.

If the wheel was simply placed on the shaft, and relied on gravity to keep it in place, it would be a single object, requiring a *single exertion of effort* to displace in an appropriate direction.

However, if it were bolted to the steering shaft, that bolt would essentially make the shaft and wheel an object in it's own right, as the two items would be inseparable by just about any means until the bolt was removed. I believe it reasonable to assume that *removing the bolt would take additional effort or a separate action.*

If you don't want to kill your game with hardware-micromanagement, I would recommend discussing and finding a consensus with your telekinetic player. You would both have an understanding of what can/can't be moved, and avoid disagreements over tiny details like bolts, glue, and such.

Comment: This seems pretty consistent with most representations of telekinesis in other media. For instance in the *Star Wars* movies, Jedi could force-pull a lightsaber or manipulate a chance cube, or with an extended exertion of effort pull a lightsaber out of ice or rip off a hunk of metal to fling at someone. Perhaps basing the limits of telekinesis powers on other media like this would be a good guideline between the player and GM.